# How to append systemctl output into a file?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I can't seem to append the output of "systemctl is-enabled autofs >> /scripts/test" as it will complete ignore the append into the file, here is my code:

is there any way to append the output into a file?

Comment: `/scripts/test` seems suspicious; do you have a `scripts` directory in `/`?

Answer (score 1):

systemctl (and many commands) returns some of it output to stderr, not stdout. Try joining stderr and stdout with the following:

```
systemctl is-enabled autofs 2>&1 >>/scripts/test
```